# How to make tiled versions of single image?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have a an image of a stone tile that I would like to make several copies or iterations so that it appears as all new images are slightly different.

I am trying to create a tile floor using an image of stone. I would like to modify the image slightly to appear different from the rest so as to not repeat. I looked into PS variables with no success.

Any thoughts?

Comment: So if I understand you correctly - you have a tree and you want a forest?

Comment: What have you tried? What resources have you looked at? What's going wrong? Showing more effort in your question will likely get you better and more clear answers

Comment: can you add the image that you are talking about? it will give you a more accurate answer

Comment: Fisrt you nee dto equalize the image then mirror it and then  clone at seams. No PS at hand to demo so you jut need to Google for it, or look here: https://tolas.wordpress.com/2009/05/26/tutorial-how-to-equalize-textures-in-photoshop/

Answer (score 1):

Using image manipulation programs, such as Adobe Photoshop to flip the image vertically and horizontally, and playing with colour hues and saturation should give you your desired result.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: thank you for your reply. I would like to do more than flipping/mirroring, etc. the same goes for color hues/saturation. If I could blend/merge two images that are very similar to create others that would be good too.

Comment: If you are familiar with coding, you can use Processing to achieve your result, giving you versatile and unique designs.
[link](https://processing.org/)

Comment: Sorry, just read your edited comment, how many different images are you after? Bulk or only a few?

Comment: I am not familiar with coding, but I have read a bit about Processing. I will follow your link. as for the number of images, maybe 12 or so? I am just trying to use one or two images to create slight variants to avoid repetition on the floor

Answer (score 0):

There's no automated method to create images with varying aspects. You need to *manually* create your variations, then you can create a pattern.

Start with a texture.....

[image]

Increase the canvas so it is double the width and double the height, placing the starting texture in the upper left corner.....

[image]

Duplicate the texture layer and move it to the other three quadrants and then use levels, curves, rotations, or other transformations to slightly alter the three duplicates.....

[image]

Choose `Select > Select All...` from the menu then choose 'Edit > Define Pattern` and you have a pattern of your tiles. You can then use that pattern as a pattern fill on any layer....

[image]

Comment: Thank you Scott for the great tutorial. Sadly, this is what I'm trying to avoid. I just read something about compositing layers??? maybe I can blend 2 layers together?

Comment: Avoid what? If this isn't what you are seeking, then your question is *exceptionally* unclear. Are you looking to eliminate seams? Your question reads as if you *want* seams.

Comment: I am sorry for the confusion, especially when using the word 'tile'. I need to create individual files of images to create floor with tile on it. seams will be good. I just don't want one file with all the images tiling in it. I will try to upload example image - I have not uploaded to this site as this is my first post. [link](http://st.houzz.com/simgs/d8e1fc8b0e6576d2_4-3555/traditional-wall-and-floor-tile.jpg)

Comment: @bob this is a correct way to go. Do you want more variations?, cut each internal square. But this implies work. The term tile applyes exactly the same to your image. Except probably the tone variations.

Comment: There is a program that might help you: http://www.bricksntiles.com/

Comment: From your description @bob , the basic process is exactly what I've outlined in this answer.

Comment: Rafael,
thank you for the link, that program looks promising.
For all those that contributed to my post, thank you. I will continue investigating the PS tips mentioned here.